# $http.transformRequest with results from an asynchronous function

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have an angular application that uses the $http service to fetch data from a remote server.  Under certain circumstances I need to append a custom header value to each request, and I would like to use the [facilities provided by the framework](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#transformingrequestsandresponses) to accomplish this.

For security reasons, the header values to be added are calculated on the angular app's web server, which means the requestTransform must first issue a request to the application web server to get the header value and add it to the $http request that fetches data from the remote server.

Is it possible to use the requestTransform for this task? Or, will need to and wrap my data fetching calls in a service, that gets the header value from the app web server before making the $http call to the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

No, transform request / response functions are synchronous so can't by used for your particular case. Fortunately request interceptors were added recently to the `1.1.x` branch of AngularJS. Those interceptors are promise-based so you can use them to do async processing before the actual call.

More info in the "Interceptors" section of [http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$http](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear. I was hoping that the transform function would happen synchronously and it sounds like it does.  so, to confirm, i can make an asynchronous request in the transform function and the 'outer' function won't be issued until the 'inner' request has returned.

Comment: @Jason I really don't think you can do async requests in transform functions... but give it a go...

Comment: oh, i misunderstood your comment.  i see what you are saying now, the transform function must complete synchronously so it's results are available to the $http service call.  got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting your Ajax transformation functions globally (through `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest`) and your transformation functions are also using $http to do a preflight request, than you might get stuck in an infinite loop, because each preflight request will call another preflight request in recursively.

So, the only option is to set the request transformation function only on your particular $http service.

Now, since trnf. functions are executed synchronously (See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L671) you might want to make sure your preflight request is also executed synchronously, but since you can't do that with $http your only option is to use another form of making a preflight ajax request (either with jQuery.ajax() or natively with plain JS).

Comment: good point, i hadn't considered the potential for an infinite loop, i will have to take that into account